# Adding paging on the sides of content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design

I have a small app i am building, and I would like to have the paging as a big arrow on the sides of the content, something like:

```
         Menu
   -------------
   << 'content here' >>
   ---------------
        footer
```

I am using bootstrap but right now the only pager they have (and angular js) is

```
        Menu
   --------------
       'content'
        [1][2][3]..
   --------------
       footer
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me to find one example, i searched without luck or if there is an idea of how this needs to be done.

I am using this template http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/4-col-portfolio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination in that

```
<nav>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and then you can give your custom css to that two buttons to make it like your example. you have to find this type of template or you have to do customized code in this bootstrap pagination.